# Nginx and Express to serve both static files and node app

Tags: express, ubuntu, nginx

i have my nodejs app at `/var/www/html/admin` and my static website at `/var/www/html/index.html`

Inside /admin i have two folders /public - angular front end app and /server the express app for my API.

the server.js file looks like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var morgan = require("morgan"); // used to see requests
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var config = require("./config");
var path = require("path");
const app = express();

const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization"
  );
  next();
});

// log all requests to the console
app.use(morgan("dev"));

// connect to our database (hosted on modulus.io)
mongoose.connect(config.database);

var apiRoutes = require("./routes/routes")(app, express);
app.use("/api", apiRoutes);

// set static files location
// used for requests that our frontend will make
app.use(express.static('public'));

// MAIN CATCHALL ROUTE ---------------
// SEND USERS TO FRONTEND ------------
// has to be registered after API ROUTES
/*app.get("*", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "./../public/index.html"));
});*/

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("We are live on " + port);
});
```

no i have the nginx conf file that looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
         listen 443 ssl default_server;
        #ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server
        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                root /var/www/html;
                try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/index.html;



        }

location  /admin/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
                rewrite ^/admin /$1 break;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to setup those two in order to have my static public website at www.example.com and have my nodejs app running at www.example.com/admin .

Answer (score 1):

Just realised that Nginx will serve all the static content including angularjs one and express will take care of the API.

So i remove the line in the server.js to serve static files and i edited the nginx conf like this

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
         listen 443 ssl default_server;
        #ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server
        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                root /var/www/html;
                try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/index.html @express;



        }

location  @express {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;

    }
}
```

then i moved my /public folder inside the root defined in nginx root /var/www/html; and now i could access it from www.mydomain.com/public and the API works.